# Why can't I alloc/init - get "Assigning retained object to unsafe property" warning?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to ARC, and I have an object which has some internal classes as members. On the init method I want to allocate new objects for them.

ClassA.h

```
#import "ClassB.h"
@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (assign) ClassB *member;
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject
@property (assign) NSString *name;
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
@synthesize member = _member;
-(id)init
{
    _member = [[ClassB alloc] init];
}
```

But I get "Assigning retained object to unsafe property" errors. I searched over the inter webs, and see no other information on this specific warning. It compiles, but gets a runtime bad access exception.

Comment: Please post the .h file with your instance variables. Your code here is incomplete.

Comment: I had the same problem until I changed the "at"property (assign) to "at"property (strong, nonatomic)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you're assigning the object to a member marked `weak`, which means that the object won't have a strong reference and will be deallocated immediately. Using `strong` or `retain` instead of `weak` or `assign` will fix that.

A larger problem with your `-init` method is that it doesn't call `[super init]`, and it doesn't return anything. At minimum, your `-init` should look like this:

```
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.member = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I kept the [super init] out for brevity, but for completeness sake you are correct. And thanks for the explanation, know I understand why IBOutlets are weak, and member objects outside of the xib need to be strong.